# strncmp() give Segmentation Fault 11 in my quick sort c programming

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I got a segmentation fault 11 with my strncmp() function. I knew where the bug is, but have no idea what cause it. 
Here is what i am trying to solve. I input a txt file that contains lots of words. Then i need to compute the frequency of each word and then sort the words. At last, output the sorted words with their frequencies. So since it is a C program, i use linked list to store the word and the frequency. Adding the word to linked list and Count the freq of each word both work well. The bug happens in my quick sort, which i use to sort words. 
My quick sort:

```
struct node *quick_sort(struct node *head, int l, int r){
    int i, j;
    int jval;
    int pivot;
    int min;
    char* test1;
    char* test2;
    i = l + 1;
    if (l + 1 < r) {
        test1 = get_char(head, l);
        pivot = get_freq(head, l);
        for (j = l + 1; j <= r; j++) {
            jval = get_freq(head, j);
            test2 =  get_char(head, j);
            printf("test 1:  %s test 2: %s\n",test1,test2);
            min = strlen(test1) < strlen(test2) ? strlen(test1) : strlen(test2);
            printf("Length 1 :%ld  Length 2: %ld    Max is: %d\n",strlen(test1),strlen(test2), min);

                   // HERE is where the bug is  
            if (strncmp(test2,test1,min)<0 && jval != -1) {         
                swap(head, i, j);
                i++;
            }
        }
        swap(head, i - 1, l);
        quick_sort(head, l, i);
        quick_sort(head, i, r);
    }

    return head;
}
```

And other associated functions:

```
int get_freq(struct node *head, int l){
    while(head && l) {
        head = head->next;
        l--;
    }
    if (head != NULL)
        return head->freq;
    else
        return -1;
}

void swap(struct node *head, int i, int j){
    struct node *tmp = head;
    int tmpival;
    int tmpjval;
    char* tmpiStr;
    char* tmpjStr;

    int ti = i;
    while(tmp && i) {
        i--;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmpival = tmp->freq;
    tmpiStr = tmp->str;
    tmp = head;
    while(tmp && j) {
        j--;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmpjval = tmp->freq;
    tmpjStr = tmp->str;
    tmp->freq = tmpival;
    tmp->str = tmpiStr;
    tmp = head;
    i = ti;
    while(tmp && i) {
        i--;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->freq = tmpjval;
    tmp->str = tmpjStr;
}

char* get_char(struct node *head, int l){
    char* res;
    while(head && l) {
        head = head->next;
        l--;
    }
    if (head != NULL){
        char * arr = head->str;
        return arr;
    }
    else
        return res;
}
```

If i change the number of min in the strncmp(), sometimes the program works. I have no idea what the wrong is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your get_char has a char *res which never gets assigned. Also, in the same function it's possible that head could become null, so you'd return the undefined char *res

Comment: I can spot one immediate problem in the quicksort algorithm itself. You're not bypassing the pivot slot on your recursion. Its the one item that is actually *in* the right place. Your partitions should surround it, but not include it. (note: this assumes the algorithm itself it even correct, which I've not verified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assign to the variable declared in `get_char` function on this line

```
char* res;
```

`Segmentation fault 11` error is generally getting called when the program accesses memory it has not allocated. In your case you are probably trying to compare a string and some random place in memory.

Comment: The likely the culprit introducing that state (which should be fixed regardless) is  `j <= r;`, which from what I see, should be `j < r;`. Regarding the `get_char()` function, `return (head ? head->str : NULL)` and entirely throw out the local variable `res`. It isn't needed.

Comment: Put it another way. The reason `get_char()` is even reaching the point of returning that indeterminate pointer is because the j-control loop is exceeding the top-limit by one. The `get_char()` function itself can be "fixed" (loose choice of wording) by throwing out the `res` variable entirely and just `return (head ? head->str : NULL)` after the while-loop advancement.